# AutoCorrect and autocomplete flag is not working for android react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, autosuggest, autocorrect, react-native-textinput

I am using Textinput component in which i want to disable suggestion strip. but autocorrect flag is not working for android side. Can any one help me?

Comment: can you attach the components code you have?

Comment: <TextInput autoFocus={!(this.state.notes && this.state.notes.length)} autoComplete={false}
fontStyle={this.props.noteTextContent.length === 0 ? "italic" : "normal"} value={this.props.noteTextContent}
onChangeText={(text) =>this.props.noteText(text)  })} ref="noteField"
                    autoCapitalize={"none"}
                    keyboardType={"default"}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    style={styles.noteTextField}
                    autoCorrect={false} multiline={true}
                   ></TextInput>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native: Android TextInput autoCorrect={false} does not disable suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143702/react-native-android-textinput-autocorrect-false-does-not-disable-suggestions)