# React Native: Android TextInput autoCorrect={false} does not disable suggestions

Tags: react-native, expo

autoCorrect={false} is suppose to force no suggestions mode, and therefore no underlining of text in the input field but it's not working.

UPDATE 8/18/18: It seems to disable the suggestions but not the underlining.

Comment: Are you sure it isn’t working? For me, it disables automatic corrections (where it inserts a correction upon pressing space, `.`, etc.) but the suggestions are still visible and tappable (which is better than nothing for us poor users).

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in React Native but you can use : `keyboardType="visible-password"` to disable autocorrect suggestions.

Comment: That's a hack. The text input I'm using is for emails, so it needs `keyboardType="email-address"`.

Answer (score 2):

autoCorrect={false}  is working some of android phones on my project but If you use with keyboardType="visible-password" is work on my project!

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in React Native.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18457

Your options for now are probably to:

- wait for a fix to come out
- or submit a PR to fix the issue in React Native
- or write your own native module for text input that has the correct behavior

Comment: If this is the issue, then supposedly it only happens on ≥Android-8.1 (API level 27).